# Referencing a static NSString * const from another class

Tags: objective-c, static, constants

In class A I have this:

```
static NSString * const kMyConstant = @"my constant string";
```

How can I reference this from class B?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should extern your string in the header, and then define the string in the implementation.

```
//ClassA.h
extern NSString * const kMyConstant;

//ClassA.m
NSString * const kMyConstant = @"my constant string";

//ClassB.h/m
#import "ClassA.h"

...
    NSLog(@"String Constant: %@", kMyConstant);
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to remove the `static` -- that specifies that `kMyConstant` is only visible in files linked with this one.

Then, declare (as opposed to *defining*) the string in Class A's header:

```
extern NSString * const kMyConstant;
```

and import that header wherever you want to use this string. The `extern` declaration says that there exists an `NSString * const` by the name `kMyConstant` whose storage is created in some other place.

If the static definition is *already* in the header, you need to move it elsewhere (usually the implementation file). Things can only be defined once, and if you try to import a file which defines a variable, you'll get a linker error.

Answer (score 4):

If it's static, you can't (that's what the static keyword is for).

If you simply declare it as a global variable, however, you can do something like this:

```
// ClassA.m

NSString *const str = @"Foo";

// ClassB.m

extern NSString *const str;

NSLog(@"str is: %@", str);
```