# what's the different between const NSString and static NSString

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to use class variable. the following two approaches work well, but I don't know what's the different between them.

```
static NSString *str1 = @"str1";
NSString *const str2 = @"str2";
@implementation StrViewController
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can change the location to where `str1` is pointing to but cannot do the same for `str2` as it is a const pointer

this will work :

```
str1 = @"Hello";
```

while this won't:

```
str2 = @"Hello";
```

Comment: so there's no difference except changeable?

Comment: not exactly. Depends on the scope. In a function for example the initialization of static is made only once (even on multiple calls to the function) while the const variable will be initialized on each call

Comment: @giorashc , what about static NSString *const str2 = @"str2";

Comment: in what context ? you cannot change the address str2 is pointing to since str2 is a const pointer

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that your variable needn't be `static` or `const`! What makes it a class variable is that it's outside any method or function.

Despite the name, `static` has nothing to do with being static (i.e. staying the same). It's a very unfortunate choice of terminology, but it comes from C and we're stuck with it. `static` has to do with the *scope* of a variable; it is implemented at the level of the file, within the scope of the file but outside of any particular methods/functions. It is used in two ways:

- Outside any method or function, `static` prevents a global variable from being seen from outside this file. See [Referencing a static NSString * const from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942458/referencing-a-static-nsstring-const-from-another-class).
- Inside a method or function, `static` ties the storage to the file as a whole rather having the variable go out of existence when the method or function ends the way an "automatic" variable does. As the inventors of C themselves put it (K&R 4.6):

> Unlike automatics, they remeain in existence rather than coming and going each time the function is activated. This means that internal `static` variables provide private, permanent storage within a single function.

That is why `static` is used in the implementation of class-vended singleton.